# Flag questions where OP says they solved it themselves in comments

Tags: feature-request, flags, answers-as-comments

I have seen a lot of questions ending up with the OP writing a comment like

- fixed!
- solved it by doing x or y
- forget it
- found it out myself

..And so on. I have a phrase to this, when I meet it: "*You could answer your own question and accept it, maybe helping other people with similar problems in the future*". (or variances, I am not native English speaking) **But very few actually does it**. It is typically first-posters with no interest in SO. They just wanted an answer, and figured it out themselves.

Those questions hang in the system, not helping no one - but they are equally searchable as the good Q&A's. Those questions are in other words "noise".

Another disadvantage by not take care of those abandoned questions is, that they seem to be not answered, and by that spoils the ability to spot out unanswered questions for a certain tag.

My suggestion: We should be able to flag those questions as "not constructive Q&A" or "This question is a dead end" (or something like that)

---

Update: You misunderstand my intention. The goal for SO is to be the ultimate Q&A site in the world, right? Is the ultimate Q&A that a person can google for a problem, see no answers, but if he or she look very carefully can read the line "Fixed" in a comment?

Comment: If the question is answerable it doesn't really matter if we never see the OP again. It can still be answered and it can still help others

Comment: see my "another"-update

Comment: `that spoils the ability to spot out unanswered questions for a certain tag`  No it doesn't.  The question *isn't actually answered*.  There is no answer.  It is thus "unanswered".  There's no reason it shouldn't show up as being unanswered.

Comment: The only one of these you should give any heed to is "solved it by doing x or y". That can be used to create a real answer (mark as community wiki if you feel guilty using someone else's answer as your own)

Comment: `Update. You misunderstand my intention. The goal for SO is to be the ultimate Q&A site in the world, right? Is the ultimate Q&A that a person can google for a problem, see no answers, but if he or she look very carefully can read the line "Fixed" in a comment?`  So you think that if I have a problem, and I see that someone else said that they could fix it, that I'm done, and that I no longer have a problem?  If so I...disagree.

Comment: You seem to be operating under the idea that once a question has a comment saying "fixed" on it it can never be answered. This isnt true. Similarly once a question has an accepted answer more answers can still be added

Comment: @Servym you have another idea of what a Q&A-site is than me. For you, the Q is enough.

Comment: @davidKonrad but you understand what your proposed flag would be is effectively "hasn't been answered **yet** ". Thats just not a sensible flag

Comment: @davidkonrad This entire site was specifically created to be *different* from all of the other Q/A sites out there.  I am merely informing you of the philosophy that the site's founders have stated as one of the core reasons that they created this site.  We know that it's different from so many other Q/A sites out there *and that's why we're here, and not there*.  And no, I'm not saying that just having a question is enough, I'm saying that we shouldn't close/delete a question just because it is currently unanswered.  We should instead hope someone will come along and answer it.

Comment: @RichardTingle, good point, but this should be open for an audit, as everything else - my suggestion.

Comment: @Servy, "_This entire site was specifically created to be different from all of the other Q/A sites out there._" Exactly.This is why I raise this issue.

Comment: @davidKonrad but you're still thinking in the old way. That the Q&A is all about it the OP and then only the dead husk is left for the googlers. We look at it from the opposite direction; its all for the googlers but hopefully the OP will be helped too

Comment: @davidkonrad So, what, you think that SO should change it's core principles to make it more like every other Q/A site out there?  No.  Very much no.  As I said, the whole reason the site was created was because those sites weren't working.  People didn't like them.  They wanted someplace different.  This is that place, and millions of people are thankful of that.

Comment: @richard, this is BS-talk. The only one who is helped in the prototype examples I came up with is the OP self, it could never help anyone else. This is exact my reason for posting this request. How could the comment "fixed" help anyone?

Comment: @davidKonrad what would you do if the comment "fixed" wasn't there

Comment: @davidkonrad It doesn't.  We're not saying that the comment *does* help anyone.  That comment can be deleted and nothing is harmed.  Of course, none of that means that the question should be closed or deleted, or that it shouldn't be answered.

Comment: @davidKonrad I still want to know what would you do if the comment "fixed" wasn't there. I think that will unlock this question

Comment: I had a good idea, helping the site and the overall idea. Please downvote me, Appearently bad answers, no answers and good answers are the same, and equally good. No answers is **especially good**, because people cant just ask or answer again. Answers from OP to themself in a comment almost twice as good. Jesus christ.

Comment: P.s. the term "self answered" usually means when the OP has posted an answer themselves. These are actually "Abandoned by the OP"

Comment: Why are you so against answering these questions? Given that your main concern is how these look to googlers: answer them then problem solved

Comment: Maybe, because they are still technically "Unanswered" until the OP selects an answer? I disagree with that idea, but that might be where david is hung up. Is that the case @davidkonrad?

Comment: @RichardTingle, what questions? I am not reluctant to anything

Comment: @davidKonrad the questions you want to flag. Why not just answer them instead?

Comment: @kevin B, Ok - havent hanged up, was just tired of the repetations

Comment: Not quit hanged up, i mean, stuck on. Is that why you consider these questions unanswerable? because the op will never "select" an answer? or is it because the OP may never see/use the answer.

Comment: @davidkonrad I am confused.  When you flag these posts, what do you want to happen?  What do you think should happen?  Are you trying to close them?  Delete them?

Comment: @RichardTingle - "_Why not just answer them instead_" have you ever answered a selfanswered question? This is not about if and how or what or when  I want to answer aquestion, This is about the quality of SO

Comment: @kevinB technically a question is unanswered  until it has an answer that is **either** upvoted or accepted

Comment: @psubsee2003, you could begin by reading my question / original post.

Comment: @davidkonrad what is wrong with answering a selfanswered question? That's where the disconnect is here. You see that as being pointless because it won't help the OP. But that's the problem. You aren't answering the question *solely for the purpose of helping the op*. You're answering the question for ***the community***. It doesn't matter whether or not the op is still looking for an answer.

Comment: @davidkonrad I did read it.  You said you wanted to flag the post.  Ok, so what would happen after it was flagged?

Comment: @davidkonrad Its no harder to answer a question with a comment that says "fixed" on it than one without. Also the terminology is getting to me: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16389217/finding-the-intersection-of-two-3d-polygons) is a self answered question. Note how I have actually answered my own question. Writing "fixed" does not make it a self answered question

Comment: @kevin B, see my original post above. It is noise when a question seems unanswered but you can see in the comments "fixed". A Q&A site should clean that up.

Comment: that isn't noise, unless it's a question that should be closed. If that's the case, close it! you can also flag the comment to have it removed because it isn't adding anything to the question.

Comment: @davidkonrad Ok, but what is wrong with cleaning it up by answering it! That way when the googlers search rather than finding nothing they find an answer

Comment: @Kevin B - THIS IS EXACTLY WHAT I AM ASKING FOR, but as it is now, there is no way to close it. How should I flag it? I only ask for the possibility to flag (or close) questions as "self answered" or something like that, People have a very hard time to understand this.

Comment: Don't mix flagging with voting to close. they have two very different purposes. If the question is unanswerable, or is off topic for one of the close reasons available, vote to close it. Otherwise, it's still a valid question, *even if the OP doesn't need an answer anymore.*

Comment: So, you want to flag the *comment*, and not the *question*, is that right, David? And the result of this flagging, to your preference, is the removal of the comment, and not the question?

Comment: OK, maybe I have doing the wrong term all the way. What I suggest is a way to delete those self-answered questions for those who are reluctant to self-answer officially. Those who go back from SO, but dont make a "this is how I do it"-answer. Those who kust come with a question, say "never mind" and rides on

Comment: The removal of the comment would indeed by ideal. Then no one would be put off answering the (perfectly valid) question

Comment: So, you're proposing a close reason that states: *"I don't feel like answering this question because the OP doesn't need an answer anymore."*. we don't need a close reason for that, just go to another question.

Comment: A stack overflow question is indended to help hundred, perhaps thousands of people, the OP is just one of those people. Why shouldn't the question be answered because **just one** of the people it was going to help figured it out on their own. Answer it --> help hundreds of people. Delete it --> help no one

Comment: @kevin B, "_we don't need a close reason for that, just go to another question_", you are wrong. People google, you know - they find that question with no answers, just a comment that the person have fixed it for himself. And what are their opinion about SO in that moment 1) feeling good? 2) feels like the link did not satisfied my expectations

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the 2 ways such a question could be dealt with

Comment: And what is the difference between questions like those, David, and questions that have no answers, nor comments from the original poster?

Comment: There's also the possibility that people google, find the unanswered question, and know the answer to it. They can then provide said answer.

Comment: @michael, have I ever said there wasnt a differnece? I cant recall - where did I even compared those?

Comment: I ask, because you seem to want to treat the two differently.

Comment: @davidkonrad if there is absolutely no difference between the two, then what differs this type of question from a question asked seconds ago that also has no answers? should it be immediately closed too? it also is relatively useless to someone reaching the site via google.

Comment: Of course I want that. I think only self-answered questions, answered in comments, should be involved. As I describe in my original post.

Comment: And so again, I ask: what is the difference between "I fixed it" questions, and questions that have no answers, nor comments from the original poster? Why would you want to delete the former, and leave the latter?

Comment: The critical point you haven't addressed is why you think questions with a comment that says "fixed" can't still be answered

Comment: Please stop editing meta-commentary into your question. A question is not where that goes. And certainly not in that quasi-ranty disgruntled format. If you have come to a conclusion you can form into a constructive answer, by all means do so. Don't destroy your own question though.

Comment: @davidKonrad we have the right to disagree that such questions are unanswerable

Comment: @bart, LOL - "_Please stop editing meta-commentary into your question. A question is not where that goes. And certainly not in that quasi-ranty disgruntled format_" - Hard not to be "disgruntled" when you are overall misunderstood. I am not "allowed" to edit my question for clarification, but it is OK thousands of people reset their own question in a comment? Will you clear your downvote if I say "fixed"?

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta, "_Why would you want to delete the former, and leave the latter?_" read my question again. And if you still not understand, read it again.

Comment: @davidKonrad we still do not understand why you think these should not be answered edit **that** into your question

Comment: Lets say you write "don't worry, I've figured out what I should do myself" do you think from that point there's no point us adding new answers, or editing existing answers? Or should this be left here for other people to refer to?

Comment: Has fixed this, I just had to go to another forum

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Where the question is clear

Although solving a problem for the OP is the spark that triggers the question in the first place; the answers aren't primarily for them, they're for everyone. As such it doesn't really matter if we never see the OP again,  the question can still be answered and still help others. If you can answer it: go for it! If you can't I expect someone else can.

The choice we are deciding between here is this:

- Delete a question with a comment saying "fixed" on it --> help no one
- Answer a question with a comment saying "fixed" on it --> help everyone who finds that question from now on

Out of those 2 the second seems more useful

## Where the question is unclear

However, sometimes people post unclear questions and then while people are asking for clarification they just post "don't worry, I fixed it". In this case **where the question is unclear** these can be closed as "Unclear what you're asking". Of course you could have done that before they wrote "I fixed it" too

Comment: Yes, but there is no answer. just a comment, "fixed it", "solved it" "never mind" - I am sure there is ten of thousands questions ending up with that.

Comment: @davidKonrad yes but that doesn't stop **someone else** answering it

Comment: @davidkonrad So then just ignore them.  If the question is answerable, and you feel like it, write your own answer.  If you don't fell like it, don't.  If you feel that the question is unanswerable, or otherwise should be closed, then vote/flag to close.  Such comments from the OP in no way affect how you should treat the question.

Comment: Well, it stop me from answering it - why should I? It _is_ answered!!

Comment: @davidKonrad and that part is the problem. Don't worry if the OP is long gone.  Answer for the Internet in general, not the OP

Comment: @davidkonrad Because SE isn't a place to answer just one person's problem.  It's a place to create a canonical set of questions and answers so that anytime any other person has the same question they can find an answer.  If you don't want to answer it, fine, don't answer it.  Nobody's forcing you to, but that most certainly doesn't mean that the question shouldn't be answered, or that someone else shouldn't answer it.

Comment: @RichardTingle, who should answer a question already answered the OP is not interested in?

Comment: @davidkonrad Anyone.  Everyone.  An expert in that field.  You.  Me.  Richard.  Anyone interested in creating a canonical reference for the answer to that question so that it will never need to be asked again.

Comment: @davidKonrad anyone who understand what stack overflow is for. I have done it. Ive answered questions which were years old from a 1 rep user. They weren't coming back. But people from google were

Comment: @RichardTingle, so do I. Have done it many times. But, in your case, they have no declared answer in comments "problem solved". How many of those "fixed" have you answered? My guess is zero.

You do not want that. 1) The possibility of gaining tag-points is 0 (zero) - 2) the possibility of the OP still here accepting your answer is almost zero (0)

Comment: @davidKonrad personally I very rarely see these, usually the OP explains how they solved it. But it would make no difference to whether I answered the question assuming I knew the answer. Even from a selfish point of view I earn far more rep from upvotes than the check mark and im helping people to boot

Comment: @davidKonrad in fact recently on the JMonkey tag (a tag I care about) I recently went through all the unanswered questions and answered all that I could to try and improve that tag. Most questions were very old and the OP long gone. This did not factor into my decision to answer them

Comment: I STILL talk about self-answered questions in comments, you seem yo have forgotten that.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to answer the core question, that you've been asked at least a half-dozen times, @david. **If** you desire to delete the questions that have "I fixed it" comments, why, and why would you not choose to do the same for questions that don't have that comment? And **if** you desire to delete just the offending comment, well, you can flag to do that now. By the way, after all this, it's not at all clear which of these you want.

Comment: @davidKonrad by which you mean where they've written "fixed it" in the comments? Calling that self answered is incredibly confusing

Comment: @davidkonrad I've updated my answer to be more clear on what to do when the question is clear vs when it is unclear

Comment: @davidKonrad are you discussing questions that fall into the "unclear" or "clear bracket

Answer (score 5):

Given the comment chain, you don't seem to understand one of the fundamental side effects of how Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange sites in general work.

### Once the question is asked and clarified, the original poster is almost irrelevant

Sure, the original poster has the right to accept an answer that help them solve the problem, but that check mark is not necessary.  Although I'm not saying you should, you could theoretically do away with the accepted answer check-mark tomorrow, and little would change about how the site operates, people would still ask questions, and people would still provide answers, and other users would still upvote helpful answers.

You seem to be concerned that once the OP doesn't care about the answer anymore it is somehow unanswerable.  The question doesn't magically change just because the OP has not come back to the site.  If it was a good on-topic and answerable question when originally asked, then it is a good on-topic answerable question now.

Questions should be only closed if the post is not answerable for some reason, or is off-topic.  Just because it is "solved" either because it has an accepted answer or because the OP somehow indicated that they fixed their problem does not change whether the question is answerable.  It may still help someone in the future, so if it doesn't have an answer and doesn't need to be closed, then we should try to provide one, not close it saying "the OP doesn't care about this question anymore".

Now if the question is one of those "typo" questions where the OP fixed it by him/herself by correcting the typo or syntax error, or is otherwise unanswerable because it is unclear, then by all means vote close it if you have the rep or flag it if you don't.  There are even close reasons specifically for these cases:

> **unclear what you're asking**
> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

and

> **off-topic/typo**
> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

so use them when appropriate and it will help clean up these question.

However, but comments like "fixed it" or "solved" from the OP do not automatically make it a typo question or unclear.  You should treat the post the same as it would if it did not have this comment.

Comment: You seem to be reluctant of the fact, that no one look in the comments for an answer, and a Q&A needs an A to function.

Comment: @davidKonrad "I fixed it" isn't an answer. **It can still be answered** even after the OP doesn't care about it anymore. It can still "get its A"; maybe in 5 minutes time. Maybe you'll answer it. Maybe I will

Comment: @davidKonrad your whole point is that the googlers should not see unanswered questions and yet you seem unprepared to have them answered. This seems like a level of cognitive dissonance that I cannot understand

Comment: @davidkonrad I've added some more details on closing question, and what might be appropriate.